# Displaying data pulled from googlesheets in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to access data from a Google spreadsheet and display it as a table in a Shiny app. After confirmation that the spreadsheet was accessed, the app continues to run without displaying anything. Printing the data to the console works, however.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  sheet <- gs_title("Google Sheet")
  data <- gs_read_csv(sheet)

  output$table <- renderTable{
    data
  }
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput('table')
  )
))
```

Answer (score 3):

In `server.R`use `renderDataTable({})` if you use `dataTableOutput()`

This code works:

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sheet <- gs_title("Google Sheet")
  data <- gs_read_csv(sheet)

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel("Test"),
                              mainPanel(dataTableOutput('table'))
                              )
                )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```